# Scaling one set of data towards another for statistical significance

Tags: statistical-significance, anova

I have 8 sets of data. Each set, L, contains 3 samples, S.

L1-L4 were tested immediately, and L5-L8 were tested after 24 hours due to equipment shortages. Due to this and the nature of the test, output values of the delayed set of data are lower than the initial set.

Right now, I am dividing the sum of each sample (S1, S2, S3 separately) from L1-L4 by the sum of the same samples from L5-L8 to find the multiplicative difference between the two sets. I am then multiplying data from L5-L8 to bring it "on par" with L1-L4.

See table for example of data L1-L8, S1:

| L | S | Value | Scaled (x1.22) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 3.845 |  |
| 2 | 1 | 4.514 |  |
| 3 | 1 | 3.729 |  |
| 4 | 1 | 3.788 |  |
| 5 | 1 | 3.295 | 4.034 |
| 6 | 1 | 2.654 | 3.250 |
| 7 | 1 | 3.755 | 4.598 |
| 8 | 1 | 3.262 | 3.995 |

Is this valid? Or, if not, is there a way of scaling L5-L8 towards L1-L4 so as to allow for statistical testing (ANOVA, in my case) of the entire set L1-L8 to achieve valid results, or will I always have to test the two sets separately?

Comment: what do samples S1, S2, S3 stand for? for example, have all items in S1 a special treatment in common? And what do L1,...L8 stand for? Maybe you can give a bit of information concerning the scientific background. This would help to understand the experimental design, and if you are lucky, one can include the effect of delayed measurement in your ANOVA model :-)

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the site.

First, as an aside, I wouldn't use the word "normalizing" here. That usually means something like "trying to make this fit a normal distribution."  What you are trying to do is scaling.

Is it valid? Well, we don't know. Doing this doesn't violate any rules of statistics, but whether it is valid is a substantive question rather than a statistical one. If you wanted to take a statistical approach, you would need data on the same samples, both immediately and after 24 hours. Then you could plot them against each other in various ways and see what was going on. Even better would be to have data at multiple time points.

Since you don't have that, you will have to figure out whether a ratio decline (which is what you have posited) is reasonable. Or is it additive? Or something else? That is would you expect:

- 4 to change to 3
- 8 to change to 6
- 6 to change to 4.5

?

Or maybe

- 4 to change to 3
- 8 to change to 7
- 6 to change to 5

?

Or something else?

Comment: Thank you for the correction! I have adjusted the title and question to better reflect what I am asking